# how to exclude kernel updates from unattended upgrades

Tags: kernel, unattended-upgrades

What do I need to do to exclude kernel updates from unattended upgrades? I would rather livepatching to update the kernel. Should i simply add "linux-image"; to the package blacklist?

Comment: This is completely different. I don't want to disable kernel updates. I don't want unattended updates to update it. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 8):

Edit the configuration file, then add all linux kernel related package to blacklist.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

Add following into blacklist.

```
linux-headers
linux-image
linux-generic
linux-modules
```

So the blacklist section would look like this.

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
      "linux-headers";
      "linux-image";
      "linux-generic";
      "linux-modules";
};
```

This means all package starting with `linux-headers` etc. will get blacklisted. NOTE: The configuration file [requires](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=753892) [regex matching](https://pimylifeup.com/unattended-upgrades-debian-ubuntu/).

You can check if it working by dry running them a.k.a test.

```
sudo unattended-upgrades --dry-run
```

This will simulate the whole unattended upgrades process, without actually running it.

Comment: While this does use regex, the answer above uses them wrong.  "linux-headers*" means "linux header" followed by zero or more "s" which isn't terribly useful if not exactly wrong.  Additionally, leaving off the "*" would match just as well.  If you don't want ot to match a prefix, you have to terminate the string with a "$".

Comment: It might be better to just match "linux-" instad of all of these... and that's the example that the file comes with.

Comment: @user10489 Where is the reference for the `$`? As far as I see in the unattended-upgrades source code, each blacklist entry is treated like a Python regex: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/tree/unattended-upgrade?h=ubuntu/jammy#n1005

Comment: My point was that 1) by default, it matches prefixes 2) they use regex not glob, so the strings above are wrong 3) the examples in the file are already correct 4) if you didn't want prefixes, you need `$` but this would also be wrong.

Comment: Yep, Regex matching is mandated as explained here https://pimylifeup.com/unattended-upgrades-debian-ubuntu/

Comment: Much better now.